# Symfony isGranted not working on Inherited Roles?

Tags: symfony

I have a user that has an inherited role of PERM_USER_READ.

when i tried to call `$this->isGranted('PERM_USER_READ');` it always returns false. Is it the default behavior of the `isGranted()` ? If so, what can i do to evaluate inherited roles on my Twig and Controllers?

Thanks!

Comment: Post security config

Comment: Of course `isGranted` works on inherited roles. You are missing something else for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try to rename your role to ROLE_PERM_USER_READ

Comment: Hi, Apparently whats the problem here is isGranted will not evaluate prefixes other than "ROLE_".

Comment: Is the problem fixed?

Comment: What I did is to create my own Utility Class to handle the Hierarchy. I really dont know if its the best way or what.

Comment: Symfony allows you to configure the hierarchy of your site's roles in the security.yml file. 
Link to the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles

Answer (score 1):

The role **must** start with `ROLE_`
As said in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles)

- > Every role must start with ROLE_ (otherwise, things won’t work as expected)
- > Other than the above rule, a role is just a string and you can invent    what you need (e.g. ROLE_PRODUCT_ADMIN).

Answer (score 0):

## Symfony 4 answer:

I find the ROLE with inherited ROLEs very confusing, so we've adopted a "a ROLE gives you ALLOWS"-system:

```yaml
ROLE_PRODUCT_MANAGEMENT:
 - ALLOW_PRODUCT_EDIT
 - ALLOW_ASSORTMENT_READ
```

We ONLY check on  ALLOW_* 'roles', which made everthing 100% less confusing.
We've ran into the same problem as you have. I've fixed that by creating a service which does the following:

```
// /vendor/symfony/security-core/Role/RoleHierarchyInterface.php
$reachableRoles = $this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoleNames($user->getRoles());

// Check wether you have the required role, can you see this ENTITY in general?
if (!in_array('ALLOW_PRODUCT_EDIT', $reachableRoles, true)) {
    return false;
}
```

## Symfony 5 answer:

Unfortunally: none so far. From the source of RoleHierachyInterface:

```
 * The getReachableRoles(Role[] $roles) method that returns an array of all reachable Role
 * objects is deprecated since Symfony 4.3.
```

We're currently in the process of upgrading to Sym5, we havent arived at this point yet. If anyone has a neat solution for this, that would be great.