# Symfony 5 : @IsGranted on method annotation doesn't work on inherited role

Tags: php, symfony, security, annotations, roles

I (obviously) searched for [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592228/symfony-isgranted-not-working-on-inherited-roles), but mine ain't none of them.

Here's my case :

- I made a custom role : `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`
- My actual user is `admin`, his only role is `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`
- The role `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` inherits the `ROLE_ADMIN`  (see below)
- I'm trying to access `/users/page/1`
- I got `Access Denied by controller annotation @IsGranted(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_RESPONSIBLE"])`

Here is my Controller :

```
//src/Controller/UserController.php

/**
 * @Route("/users")
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 */
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private $security;
    private $mailer;


    public function __construct(Security $security, MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/page/{!page}", name="user_index", requirements={"page"="\d+"}, defaults={"page":1})
     * @IsGranted({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_RESPONSIBLE"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository, int $page = 1): Response
    {
[....]
}
```

And my custom role hierarchy

```
config/packages/security.yaml

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_RESPONSIBLE: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

I double checked every character just in case i had a typo, i don't...

I thought it was like a `&&` evaluation (user had to got `ROLE_ADMIN` **and** `ROLE_RESPONSIBLE`).

**EDIT:** That was the problem, the default behavior is a `&&` evaluation of each role in the array, i needed to use `* @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_RESPONSIBLE')")`

I tried only with `@IsGranted("ROLE_USER")`, it worked but `@IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")` does not, and it's an inherited role

[I (still) can't embed an image so take my word on that or see my proof here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkpBY.png)

Thanks in advance, mondays are mondays you know ...

Comment: Does IsGranted("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN") work?  The answer might help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes it does, `IsGranted("ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH")` works too.
So that's what i thought ... But i need to have access for both `ROLE_RESPONSIBLE` and `ROLE_ADMIN` ...

Comment: In symfony 4.4 `@IsGranted({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_RESPONSIBLE"})` works as expected (ROLE_ADMIN **OR** ROLE_RESPONSIBLE), but in symfony 5 it doesn't work correctly (RoleVoter just skips checking and returns access denied).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're requiring the user be granted two roles. Change your hierarchy to make ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN inherit ROLE_RESPONSIBLE so you can remove it or change the annotation to :

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_RESPONSIBLE')")
 */
```

Comment: That's exactly what i need ! A `or` statement.  
I have found info about that [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html)  
Note to others : Be careful while autowiring, you need to import `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security as SecurityCore;`, because i also need `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;` but there was obviously a namespace conflict.  

Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

I think your admin need to have **ROLE_RESPONSIBLE** too since you provide an array of roles in your @isGranted() annotation.

`/**
 * @Route("/page/{!page}", name="user_index", requirements={"page"="\d+"}, defaults={"page":1})
 * @IsGranted({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_RESPONSIBLE"})
 */
public function ...`

Comment: That's a solution but it would totally defeats the purpose of having two separate roles.. (`ROLE_RESPONSIBLE` and `ROLE_ADMIN`)

Comment: You need to explain what you want to achieve, you want the action to be accessible to users who have "ROLE_ADMIN" AND "ROLE_RESPONSIBLE" or to have "ROLE_ADMIN" OR "ROLE_RESPONSIBLE" (one of them)?

Comment: I needed that : `@Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_RESPONSIBLE')")` 
(see approved answer)
There's no point of making two separate roles otherwise.